# IntelliJ-IDEA: how to enforce same code style

Tags: intellij-idea

We are using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5. How can we ensure that everyone is using the same code style and Rearranger configuration? What files should be put under version control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should share most of the files in `.idea` directory when using the directory based format, [check the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).

In the [Code style settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-style.html) make the current scheme project specific, it will be stored in `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` (or project `.ipr` file when using the legacy format).

Rearranger is a third-party plug-in and as far as I know doesn't store its configuration inside the project. It has options to import configuration from a file and export it to a file which you can use to maintain the same configuration by putting this file in the version control.

Note that IDEA 12 will bundle a new Rearranger plug-in which will have better configuration management (similar to the code style settings, or a part of it).

Comment: With IDEA 15, has this changed at all? We want to share as much as we can, but can't find in the docs how to do this... it seems very scattered, though likely supported...

Comment: @cdeszaq yes I believe this is still valid on 15

Comment: @CrazyCoder how do you deal with conflicts when plugins change the codeStyleSettings.xml file? more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757069/stop-intellij-from-modifying-codestyles-xml