# Stop IntelliJ from modifying codeStyleSettings.xml

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We have our codeStyleSettings.xml in version control (git) in order to standardize code style across the engineering org, just like in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087439/how-to-share-code-style-settings-between-developers-in-intellij) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709733/intellij-idea-how-to-enforce-same-code-style). However, we keep running into the issue where IntelliJ (or a plugin) would change the codeStyleSettings.xml file and sometimes the developer would accidentally check in the changes.

I've tried things like `git update-index --skip-worktree [<file>...]`, which solves the problem for most cases, except for when an upstream change comes in from the remote, and a conflict occurs (because there's a change in the local version of the file, but because of the `--skip-worktree` command, won't actually show up on a `git status`.)

Preventing IntelliJ from making automatic changes to this file seems like the best course of action (if even possible), but is there another way? I'm trying to make it as painless for the development team as possible. The team is split between IntelliJ 14 and 15 for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration server plugin https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/synchronizing-and-sharing-settings.html?origin=old_help

We are using this in our company. It works fine, but still needs some improvement. You can set the repository read-only so the people can't change the codestyles for other users.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for this, What are some of the improvements that need to be made?